# Removing Entity from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am doing some tests with `GAE/J`.

Some days ago I created a model and I have persisted some instances [twig-persist](http://code.google.com/p/twig-persist/).
Now that class doesn't exist any more and I want to remove that instances.

Can I do it from the `Data Viewer` or I can only remove it from the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Datastore Viewer (on the GAE dashboard) will let you do it, but it's a bit painful if you have a lot of entities. You can only delete them twenty at a time.

The alternative is to create a new model with the same name and create a handler that deletes them via code.

Comment: I only have 4 instances. How do you do it from the dataviewer?

Comment: When you go into the viewer, there is a drop down menu at the top that lets you select the Entity kind. Click that drop down and select the kind you're looking for, toggle the all-entities box and click 'delete'.

Comment: my bad. I didn't see that the first time. Thanks.